# Best way to show Feeds on mobile with 5 fields of data

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, activity-feed

I need to show 5 data fields on mobile, which is notification feed. Currently I am showing following 4 fields with distribution as
1. title - first line ( can extend to second if title is long )
2. Group Name and Date / Time - Second line
3. Description Summary - Third and Fourth Line

Now I Need to show "author name" along with above three fields.

Can anyone suggest best space for "author name".

Here is screenshot of page I am currently developing

[image]

-- Vishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like below

[image]

1. Separate the Notification by date

   - Usability wise user will be easily distinguish the notification by date
   - It frees the space for date/time
2. I would suggest to put the time on right, Reason it'll always take limited space on screen since date part it gone :)
3. You can change the color of component according to your need. Here I though author should be prominently visible to the user (its blue in color)
4. You can switch the author name and group name position (it make sense to put author name just below the title)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try the amazon approach, i.e., author below title in a smaller font size:
[image: Amazon Web approach]

Or, if applicable, you could do Title and append by Author. Something like: The Norton Anthology of Western Music by Burkholder. You could also use a smaller font size for the author like in the previous approach.

Personally, and for mobile, I prefer to use the first approach.

Comment: your suggestion might look good on desktop. On MObile I do not have enough space. 1. sometimes my title iteself spills onto second line. 2. Group Name is also sometimes long enough to cover entire line. -- Vishal

Comment: Can you post a mock of your interface?

Comment: added screenshot

Answer (score 0):

How important is the author name?

a) If it's fairly important, it could go before the title, in the same line, divided by a colon or a dash. I would limit the length of "author - title" to max two lines, if we want to see enough from the title.

b) If the author is not so important, it could logically go with before the group name, divided for example by "in" word.

To save space you can optimize the timestamps little bit. "Today" can be skipped. And the time is usually a side information, so the font could be smaller.

Comment: thanks teepee, for your view. It was one of my primary considerations also. But as date / time can be like "yeasterday, 05:05 PM" also, which can take almost half of the screen. Apart, Group Name also can be larger, it may take half of the screen. Sometime Author name can be larger which also might take half of the screen. anyways, liked option to play with font size.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you add height for each segment? then you can have enough room for the info.
About the date/time, if it's yesterday or longer time ago, you don't have to show the specific
time, you can show "yesterday" "Sunday" etc.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective Author Name is close related information with a Date od the message. 
I think that a place under "Yesterday, 08.00 PM" will be most valuable for potential user who is looking for information about Who & When the message was sent.